# extract multiple columns from pyspark dataframe column using regexp_extract

Tags: pyspark

Need to extract multiple columns that have duplicate tags from pyspark dataframe column using  regexp_extract. But it is extracing only first match.

```
source data from pyspark Dataframe column
df - data
ABC:26B:XYZ//UNIT/111,:17A:ACCT//1011112:17A:BNK//123:          
DDD:25A:XYZ//UNIT/111,:17A:MMT//11234:17A:ACK//9999999: 

code used is:
df = df.withColumn('17', F.trim(F.regexp_extract(F.col('data'), ':17.?:(.*?):',1)))  

This is extracting only first match, need the second match as well.

current output:
17            
ACCT//1011112  
MMT//11234 

Expected Output:
17A_1            17A_2
ACCT//1011112    BNK//123
MMT//11234       ACK//9999999
```

Comment: The last parameter ID of F.regexp_extract(col, pattern, ID) indicates the matched group. If you want the second group, you have to add another column for it. df.withColumn('17', F.trim(F.regexp_extract(F.col('data'), ':17.?:(.*?):',1)))..withColumn('17_2', F.trim(F.regexp_extract(F.col('data'), ':17.?:(.*?):',2)))

Comment: Getting this error, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Regex group count is 1, but the specified group index is 2, please suggest

Comment: can you try this regex?  df.withColumn('17', F.trim(F.regexp_extract(F.col('data'), ':17.:([A-Z]+\/\/[\d]+),1))).withColumn('17_2', F.trim(F.regexp_extract(F.col('data'), ':17.:([A-Z]+\/\/[\d]+)',2)))

Comment: getting same error

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_extract` returns only 1 match but if you are using newer version of Spark, you can use SQL's `regexp_extract_all`. (there is no Pyspark's function yet)

Also, the `(.*?)` will do greedy match so I tweak the regex.

```
df = df.withColumn('17', F.expr('regexp_extract_all(data, "(?<=:)17.?:(.+?):", 1)'))
```

Regex explanation

```
(?<=:)17 => positive lookbehind. Match 17 followed by :
(.+?): => lazy match. finds the next :
```

Check here about greedy vs lazy match
https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

Comment: This is helpful, we have limitations on our environment and we are not able create this function in hive.